# The boy is coming singing

Tags: grammar, verbs, present-participles

Consider the following two sentences:

[1] The boy is coming.
[2] The boy is singing. (at the same time)

How can I join the two sentences using a participle? Can I use any of the  sentences below?

[3a] The boy comes singing.
[3b] The boy is coming while singing.
[3c] The boy is singing while coming.
[3d] The boy is coming singing.
[3e] The boy is coming, singing.

Comment: "The boy is singing while he comes." is the most clear, I think, but "The boy is coming, singing." has a nice poetry to it.

Comment: Be aware that the verb *to come* has a slang meaning.

Comment: @Deadrat - why do you think it is not the intended meaning ?:)

Comment: @Josh61 Probably a projection of my own lack of musical talent.

Comment: 3a is also clear to me and the most succinct

Comment: Why specifically do you have to use the word "coming"? It's a vague word. How about "approaching" or "arriving"?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: 3a is the only one where the immediate and most obvious interpretation is that the boy is approaching while singing. All the others sound like the boy is singing a tune whilst having an orgasm, which, as noted by Josh and deadrat, may or may not be desirable. (The interpretation, that is. Orgasms are generally quite desirable.)

Answer (score 1):

As English has very limited inflectional morphology, sometimes it becomes really difficult to recognize finite verb form  the non finite (verbals). The poster poses exactly that glaring problem area.

We know finite verbs are bound in time, space and aspects in its relation to subjects; verbals have no such obligations.The paradox of the situation is such that COMING / SINGING both  qualify  as finite verbs and one AND  in-between is enough to solve it.  But the environment surrounding the verbs is proof enough what is what :

- Is coming — tensed participle
- Singing —Verbal(non finite)

We are not bound by any rule to put these lookalikes together and we must not with due respect to their functional disparities and sanctity of semantic order.

Make SINGING the head word, the problem is solved.  All other sentences where meaning can easily be gathered and which are not strained, reflect the sense to be convyed ; but never in "COMING SINGING" combination.

Comment: *Coming* is not a tensed verb; it is a non-finite verb form that carries no tense. *Came*, in contrast, *is* a tensed verb.

Comment: We ordinarily consider the verb phrase, ' is coming ' as the verb in making present continuous tense; it may be treated from common man's  perspective. Great things are too great for me

Answer (score 0):

This might seem old-school but: "The boy comes a singing"

Comment: I'd go past "old-school" to "archaic" :)

Comment: hyphenate that: "he comes a-singing"

Answer (score 0):

```
[3b] The boy is coming while "he is" singing.
[3c] The boy is singing while "he is" coming.
[3e] The boy is coming, singing.
```

I think this sounds ok. But I guess you must use "he is"

Comment: Sorry. I forgot it @janus-bahs-jacquet

Comment: @Zan700 That was edited in after my comment. I'll delete my comment above since it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> [3a] "The boy comes singing."

Grammar ok, 
Comparable to "Come dancing!" or "I come bearing gifts".

> [3b] "The boy is coming while singing."

Grammar ok. Comparable to  "The boy is drinking while driving"

> [3c] "The boy is singing while coming."

Grammar ok. Comparable to "The boy is coughing while serving food."

> [3d] "The boy is coming singing."

Incorrect

> [3e] The boy is coming, singing.

Grammar ok. Comparable to "The boy is leaving, carrying his suitcase, laughing as he goes."

To put together "sing" and "come" a little better, use "as", without the second present participle:

"The boy is singing as he comes through the door."

"The boy is coming forward as he sings the last stanza"